# excavator arm rigging issue - help needed

Tags: rigging

I'm about to loose my mind seeking for a solution...

I already did the basic rigging for an excavator arm and the pistons. Now I want to do an additional more complex one for the shovel. I tried several ways but the second point at the shovel just won't fit / keeps on moving...

May be someone has a simple solution to get my brain back on track?
Pls see attached file for details + to play around.

[image]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/96Q0v6M3/

Comment: maybe this helps? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwUBd3HX3Xw

Comment: sometimes it really is that easy!
Thank you so much @Chris !
I wonder why this did not pop up in my search... maybe my brain was just to exhausted yesterday ‍♂️

I'll check it out and post the final blender file later on...

Comment: you linked 2 times the same video... ;)

Comment: I would suggest to first checkout this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZaNZhAoMts
 
Then follow up starting at 30min in this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwUBd3HX3Xw 

What a smart idea to create an additional bone at the connections in the second tutorial! This one was of bad quality and hard to follow but at least did the job and gave the solution. Many thanks to Amit!

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/Erz10w4G/